# Alterar HREF de um link caso a url não atenda a alguns requisitos

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho uma dúvida. Preciso forçar o valor da página 1 de uma páginação pra uma URL específica. Não consegui descobrir como altarar o código do plugin que estou usando, portanto decidi fazer uma "gambiarra" para eu poder colocar o sistema em produção. Eu gostaria de, via JQUERY, alterar o atributo HREF de uma determinada tag "A" , se a classe dela for "page smaller" e se a url definida não tiver a string "page". Mas estou apanhando no JS. Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
    $(function(){
                if(!$('a[href*="page"]') && $('a').hasclass('page smaller')){    
    $("a").attr("href", "http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/0")
                }
});
```

Em resumo, preciso forçar que o link que aponta para http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/ , aponte para http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/0

Eis o código da paginação para ilustrar

```
<div class="wp-pagenavi">
<span class="pages">Página 3 de 44</span>
<a class="previouspostslink" rel="prev" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/2/">«</a>
<a class="page smaller" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/">1</a>
<a class="page smaller" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/2/">2</a>
<span class="current">3</span>
<a class="page larger" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/4/">4</a>
<a class="page larger" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/5/">5</a>
<span class="extend">...</span>
<a class="larger page" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/10/">10</a>
<a class="larger page" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/20/">20</a><a class="larger page" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/30/">30</a>
<span class="extend">...</span>
<a class="nextpostslink" rel="next" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/4/">»</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode pegar o elemento com `.page.smaller:not([href*=page])`.

Isso trará todos os elementos que possuem as classes `page` e `smaller` no qual o atributo href não contém a sequência "page":

```js
$(function(){

  $('.page.smaller:not([href*=page])')
     .attr('href', 'http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/0');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wp-pagenavi">
  <!-- ... -->
  <a class="page smaller" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/">1</a>
  <a class="page smaller" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/2/">2</a>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Como <s>sugestão</s> alternativa, visto que está querendo somente concatenar o `page/0` no href já definido no elemento, ao invés de colar a URL absoluta você pode fazer assim:

```js
$(function(){

  $('.page.smaller:not([href*=page])')
     .attr('href', function(i, href){
        return href + 'page/0';
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wp-pagenavi">
  <!-- ... -->
  <a class="page smaller" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/">1</a>
  <a class="page smaller" href="http://10.31.0.137/wordpress/index.php/ajax-fonte/page/2/">2</a>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado funcionou corretamente.

Comment: @Leibovich Editei a minha resposta e inclui uma alternativa que pode ser melhor.